# Installing pip to a custom location

Tags: linux, debian, python, pip

I am a little bit stuck when it comes to installing pip.

```
Securely download get-pip.py. [2]

Then run the following (which may require administrator access), to install (or upgrade to) the latest version of pip:

$ python get-pip.py
```

The trouble is with this approach is it installs it to a different path than what is expected. So I have to do this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

Is there a way to install it with that path, or alternatively can I do something like this:

```
/user/local/bin/pip install supervisor
```

Finally, is this better than installing pip with either:

- apt-get install python-pip
- easy-install pip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ apt-get install python-pip
```

That's the one you want.

Unless your requirements dictate otherwise, **always** use your distribution's packages.